anyone can explain this error simulate transaction?

i using raydium sdk v2, since i already ask about the code on that repo, the creator said the code is okey, but the Keypair is wrong, but i use same keypair for get the data on Connection.getAccountsInfo and the PublicKey is fine from that keypair

Check owner correctly.
